# RestKit 0.2 result is an array of nil objects, although mapping seems to be succesful

Tags: ios, restkit

I am currently trying to make RestKit 0.20 run with my current project and i am experiencing some difficulties.

I tried mapping my request to an object and it is apparently mapping, but only returning null objects as a result.

May you guys know what to do.

This is the code

```
// Create object mapping for MVMyCar
  RKObjectMapping *mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[MVMyCar class]];
  [mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                @"my_car_id"        :   @"uuid"
                                                }];

  // ResponseDescriptor
  RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:mapping
                                                                                          method:RKRequestMethodGET
                                                                                     pathPattern:kAPIPathGarage
                                                                                         keyPath:@"result"
                                                                                     statusCodes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:200]];
  [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];

  [RKObjectManager.sharedManager getObjectsAtPath:kAPIPathGarage parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
    NSLog(@"Mapping: %@",[mappingResult array]);
  } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

  }];
```

This is the restkit trace:

```
2013-07-18 18:32:01.566 [12722:3a07] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:953 Performing mapping operation: <RKMappingOperation 0xc2920b0> for 'MVMyCar' object. Mapping values from object {
    "my_car_id" = 76;
} to object *nil description* with object mapping (null)
2013-07-18 18:32:01.569 [12722:3a07] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:550 Mapping attribute value keyPath 'my_car_id' to 'uuid'
2013-07-18 18:32:01.572 [12722:3a07] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:431 Found transformable value at keyPath 'my_car_id'. Transforming from type '__NSCFString' to 'NSNumber'
2013-07-18 18:32:01.573 [12722:3a07] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:572 Mapped attribute value from keyPath 'my_car_id' to 'uuid'. Value: 76
2013-07-18 18:32:01.574 [12722:3a07] D restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:1021 Finished mapping operation successfully...
```

And this is the result, which is actually right in number: 13 elements.

```
2013-07-18 18:32:01.575 [12722:3a07] D restkit.object_mapping:RKMapperOperation.m:403 Finished performing object mapping. Results: {
    result =     (
        (null),
        (null),
        (null),
        (null),
        (null),
        (null),
        (null),
        (null),
        (null),
        (null),
        (null),
        (null),
        (null)
    );
}
```

Many thanks!

Comment: I am wondering whether it has something to do with: "to object *nil description* with object mapping (null)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found the error. Quite stupid to be honest:

I had an attribute in my mapped object which was named "description".

Sometimes one cannot see the wood for the trees.